# git pull branch with absolute path

Tags: git, path, branch, absolute, pull

I've been using the following command for checkout:

```
git --git-dir=C:/home/www/project/.git --work-tree=C:/home/www/project/ checkout branch
```

I'm trying to replicate the same behavior for pull:

```
git --git-dir=C:/home/www/project/.git --work-tree=C:/home/www/project/ pull origin branch
```

It fails with the following error:

```
fatal: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

What's wrong? Why it's not working? Please help!

Comment: I have found this link: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/quot-git-pull-quot-doesn-t-respect-work-tree-parameter-td5857182.html -- Is this still not solved? Hm...

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you cannot run (cd c:/home/www/project && git pull origin branch) assuming you are using the msysgit bash shell.